# Bootstrap Datepicker seems to not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with date picker. Search some answers too but doesn't seem to help, here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../datepicker/css/datepicker.css" />

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Date"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the datetimepicker is a separate plugin.... looks like you are missing the plugin js file

Comment: may be you want to say `$('#datetimepicker1')..datepicker({
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I forgot to paste the plugin. edited now. but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The #datetimepicker1 should be in the **input**, not in the **div**. So try this:

```
<div class='input-group date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Date" id='datetimepicker1' />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: After further Googling, I found out  it has something to do with modal and datepicker z-axis. Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `jQuery` selector to `$('**.input-group.date**').datepicker()`;

The DIV is necesaary for datepicker to be initiated.
Please refer to http://jsbin.com/lerojivu/1/edit

---

The variant `zIndex` in source code

```
place: function ()...
```

Due to using the modal z-index property is zero.
It can be amended listed below.

```
var parentZIndexes = this.element.parents().map(function() {
                           return parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) || 0;
                      });
var zIndex = Math.max.apply(Math, Array.prototype.slice.apply(parentZIndexes)) + 10;
```